# Aptify (.NET CRM Solution) to MailChimp Synchronization

Tags: .net

I'm trying to determine what is involved in synchronizing MailChimp, the popular bulk email service, with Aptify, the .NET-powered CRM my company uses.  MailChimp supplies a .NET wrapper DLL which should make this process much easier.  They also advertise a 3rd-party solution:

> Sync Module for .Net systems - MailChimp Sync Module makes it easier for developers to synchronize their lists from any datasource to mailchimp. It has been developed in C# on the mailchimp .NET wrapper. Check it out here. Provided by Wim De Coninck.

What steps would have to take to use these tools to get MailChimp and Aptify playing nicely together?

Answer (score 0):

Integrating other components into our platform is fairly easy, including COM components if need be.  Consulting recently completed an integration piece with Magnet Mail, a service with similiar features.  Aptify has a community site you could have asked this question on as well.  Email me for more details on integration and/or the community site.

Stephen